# При парсинге строки в int, получаю ошибку "error":"strconv.ParseInt: parsing \"373\\r\": invalid syntax"

Tags: golang, docker

Очевидно, что ошибка в том, что строка содержит не только числа, однако эта ошибка возникает, только в том случае, если я клонирую репозиторий с github. Локальная версия этого проекта отрабатывает без ошибок. Возможно ли что github добавляет какие- то символы в файлы? И есть ли готовые решения на этот случай. Ссылку оставил
https://github.com/RuslanU1703/skillbox-final-practical-work

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А сам dockerfile не покажите? Ну или хотя бы стектрейс полноценный, вместо куска ошибки..

Comment: Вообще, судя по коду, у вас скорей всего в переменной окружения PORT какая-то ересь указана вместо номера порта

Comment: По поводу dockerfile, я же скинул ссылку на репо, там весь код вообще. Почему вы считаете, что порт не правильный? В docker compose описана сеть для общения контейнеров, соответственно запросы идут не по localhost:port а по container_name:port. Ладно, это все лирика, проблема в том, что ошибка вообще не связана с этим никак, у меня ошибка в конвертации string to int. Когда я запускаю docker compose up, с уже клонированного проекта, все запускается, но в обычной операции по переводу строки в число возникает ошибка, которой не было локально, при абсолютно идентичном коде, который я и пушил